# Is it possible to change the way PyCharm displays the OpenCV documentation?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, documentation

PyCharm (PY-193.6911.25, macOS 10.15.4) doesn't correctly display the OpenCV documentation.

More concretely, this is the result.

[image]

As you can see, it's a mess. Is it possible to fix this? I installed OpenCV with pip.

Answer (score 1):

- In PyCharm 2020.1.1 professional edition with Python 3.7, the following warning is displayed for the `cv2` docstring

  - `You need configured Python 2 SDK to render Epydoc  docstrings`
- [Epydoc](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000027644-Pycharm-can-t-render-Epydoc-docstrings) is a tool for generating API documentation for Python modules, based on their docstrings.
- [Pycharm can't render Epydoc docstrings](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000027644-Pycharm-can-t-render-Epydoc-docstrings)

  - *The suitable interpreter is looked up among those configured in the IDE (it has to be Python 2 since Epydoc package itself hasn't been ported to Python 3 yet). In other words, you need to set up it once so that it showed up on the list at Settings | Project: ... | Project Interpreter | Show All... -- it doesn't need to be actually used in any project. Is it true in your case?*
  - *The problem is that it's not really Epytext. OpenCV uses Doxygen for documentation that we don't support and also confuse with Epytext because of the similarity of tags. There is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30342) about it.*
- [Doxygen is confused with Epydoc and displayed as free text (not preformatted)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30342)

  - *I'm afraid this particular feature of PyCharm is not really extensible at the moment. Besides, displaying of documentation, injecting references to symbols inside it, completion of available tags and generation of documentation stubs -- everything is tied very closely to the fact that in Python code documentation is normally provided via designated string literals, not comments. The highest level API you can plug into to provide custom documentation source for Quick Documentation popup/tool window is [`com.intellij.lang.documentation.DocumentationProvider`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/analysis-api/src/com/intellij/lang/documentation/DocumentationProvider.java) if you register yours before the default one with ID `pythonDocumentationProvider`. But it will cover only rendering, everything else will need to be written from scratch.*
- The official resolution is ***we don't support that***

Answer (score 1):

After googling a lot I ended up thinking there is no easy solution but... there actually is!

What i did is:
Push CTRL Q
Scroll down to the trippledot and click open source.
Push CTRL+R(replace)
replace '.   ' to ''
Now docstring looks like this:
[image]
Definately not perfect, but i think it looks a bit better.

Additionally i added this as external documentation:
[https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q={element.name}&check_keywords=yes&area=default](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=%7Belement.name%7D&check_keywords=yes&area=default)

So it brings up a cv2 'tutorial'...